# I'm trying to change how many items a map function with map with a click of a button, but it doesn't work when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, array.prototype.map

```
  render(){
    let size = 5;
    let addFive = function(size){
        return size += 5
    }
  return(
     {pastTrackers.slice(0, size).map((pastTracker,index)=>{
         return(
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
          )
      })}
     <Button onClick={this.addFive}>Show 5 More</Button>
   })
```

I'm slicing the list so it only shows the first five items of the array, but then there is a button that is supposed to add five more to the array but when I click it doesn't add anymore.

Comment: You need to use `setState` if you want to trigger another render.

Comment: You are trying to call the local variable function using this instance  this.addFive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(...args)
{
  super(...args)
  this.state = {
    currentSize: 5
  }
}

get items() {
 pastTrackers.slice(0, this.state.currentSize)
} 

this.addFive() {
  this.setState({
    currentSize: this.state.currentSize + 5
  })
}

render(){
  return(
     {this.items.map((pastTracker,index)=>{
         return(
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
          )
      })}
     <Button onClick={() => { this.addFive() }}>Show 5 More</Button>
   })
```

Comment: Because state updates may be async you shouldnt reference `this.state` in `setState` calls rather leverage the function API of setState `function increaseSize (state, props) {return {score : state.size + 1}}`

Answer (score 1):

`render` doesn't get executed again unless you modify the state of the component. Nothing in your `addFive` function modifies its state, so `render` isn't re-run.

Instead, you'd hold the size in your `this.state`, and use

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ size: prevState.size + 5 }));
```

...to update it and trigger a re-rendering.

Live Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      size: 5,
      values: [
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
        "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
        "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen"
      ]
    };
    this.addFive = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({size: prevState.size + 5 }));
    };
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.state.values.slice(0, this.state.size).map(value => <span>{value} </span>)}
      <hr />
      <input type="button" onClick={this.addFive} value="+5" />
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

(Note: [Yes, you do need to use the callback version](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). `this.setState({size: this.state.size + 1})` would be wrong, because you're setting new state based on existing state.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function (`addFive`) doesn't modify the `size` variable. It just returns it (+ 5, that is). Also, the size should be part of your component's state. If it's not, changing it won't trigger a new rendering cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
let addFive = function(size) {
    this.setState(state => ({
        size: state.size + 5
    }));
}
```

Just use setState (which also accepts a function as input)